# self.view.bounds in iOS 8 after rotation to portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ios7, autolayout, ios8, autorotate

In my app, I am dynamically using self.view.bounds to position subviews and I am not using Autolayout. When the view is rotated to portrait mode on iOS 8, I see self.view.bounds to be {568, 320} after view appears as opposed to natural behavior of {320,568} on iOS 7. How do I get this right ?

EDIT : I forgot to mention where I am doing this. This happens in viewDidAppear:. The value of self.view.bounds is incidentally correct in viewWillAppear but somehow it gets screwed up in viewDidAppear:.

EDIT 2: Here is I found on further drilling. Following is the scenario unique to my code :

a. Auto rotation is BLOCKED by me in code by returning only landscape orientation when the view is starting (this has to do with the camera & opengl setup I am doing and I do not want to autorotate the interface till everything is setup,

b.The view is freeform in XIB and has flexible width, height and all the edges in autoresizing mask.

c. Based on the above resize mask, iOS 7 gives self.view.bounds size equal to {320, 568} even though auto rotation has not happened. iOS 8 somehow ignores the same resize mask & the bounds is still {568,320}

So the root of the problem is UIWindow is autorotating in iOS 8 with the device while View controller is denying to autorotate.

Comment: the `frame` and `bound` are adjusted to the `UIWindow` _after_ the view has been added to the navigation stack and it is about being visible on the screen – _before_ that those values are undetermined, usually they are populated from the `xib` temporarily. (the right value is `(320; 568)` in portrait mode on iPhone5)

Comment: Where are you doing this? In `viewWillLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: @JoeFryer, I assume it happens at earlier stage of the view's lifecycle – in `–viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @holex well he said 'when the view is rotated to portrait', so I assume it is after `viewDidLoad`, and is in response to the rotation.

Comment: @JoeFryer, yes, _after_ the rotation it gets its proper values, but he would read the values _before_ that is why he does not understand why it changes.

Comment: This is happening in viewDidAppear:...Its fine in viewWillAppear but gets screwed up later.

Comment: I am trying to understand why iOS 7 & iOS 8 behave differently. In viewDidAppear, I go and call my manual layout routine and read self.view.bounds. The result is correct in iOS 7 but not in iOS 8.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, it is not _"screwed up later"_... it is adjusted properly to `UIWindow` after the view appears or after rotation. you may need to learn more about orientation support to understand what is happening at each stage of the view's lifecycle: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

Comment: @DeepakSharma, you can read more about the iOS8's features and behaviours here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html

Comment: @holex As far as I understood viewDidAppear: is the safest place to put manual layout code because by that time self.view.frame and bounds would have got its proper value.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, yep, that is true. your assumption is correct – but bear in mind the iOS8 SDK is in _beta_ stage, still. however, if you read `(320; 568)` in portrait mode that would be correct because that is the **correct** bound. (first value is the `width` the second one is the `height` of the screen.)

Comment: This is very strange as it happens in viewDidAppear:...my suspicision is there is something different in autorotation behavior on iOS 8. Need to nail it down.

Comment: @holex I read 320:568 in viewWillAppear: but it changes back to 568:320 in viewDidAppear:

Comment: Same code running on iOS 7 simulator gives correct bounds but not on iOS 8 simulator or device running iOS 8 beta 5.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, that does not seem correct... I refer back to my earlier comment about the iOS8 is still in _beta_ stage – you may need to report is as bug.

Comment: I wonder can this be a bug, as lot of apps will break.

Comment: I made a new project in XCode 6 and using storyboards, there is no problem in it. Only my app that is using Xib and without autolayout + Xib is created for iPhone 4 interface and the code later adapts for iPhone 5 interface. Trying to create bare minimum sample code where it shows.

Comment: the iOS8 is _beta_ and it is for testing purpose only; time for updating the existing applications comes a bit later when the _Xcode6_ will be ready for commercial development – updating a live app or developing a new one _before_ that would be a very unwary idea.

Comment: It's nothing to do with beta. The problem is in iOS 8, UIWindow transforms its bounds depending on iPhone orientation whereas in iOS 7 & below, UIWindow bounds remain same no matter what orientation.

Comment: @DeepakSharma did you find a solution?  I am seeing a similar issue in commercial version of xcode 6 / ios 8.

Comment: I converted xibs to storyboards, that's the solution that worked for me @AliciaCano .

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8, the rectangle returned by `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` takes into account the rotation of the device. No longer will the portrait frame be returned when the device is in landscape.

The [updated-for-iOS-8 docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/bounds) for `UIScreen -bounds` state:

> This rectangle is specified in the current coordinate space, which takes into account any interface rotations in effect for the device. **Therefore, the value of this property may change when the device rotates between portrait and landscape orientations**.

Prior to iOS 8, the discussion section simply said:

> Contains the bounding rectangle of the screen, measured in points. (read-only)